# Drawing basic shapes in mordern opengl, which approach is better?

Tags: opengl, rendering, shapes

1. Preallocating a vertex buffer in the GPU and then filling it vertex data and then drawing them to replicate legacy opengl functions like `glVertex2f`, `glNormal2f` etc and drawing shapes with them.
2. Sending the vertex data of all the primitive shapes to the GPU at once at the start of the program then drawing the appropriate part of it in the vertex shader when drawing the shape.

These are all the ways I could think of but I'm not sure how optimal either of these approaches are.
Do games and game engines use a similar approach? or is there an even better approach to this?

Comment: You found a library that uses neither of the two approaches you use. Instead it uses a third approach. And this makes you *more* uncertain of which approach to use? Have you found *anyone* using the two approach you're using? Also, what do you mean by "drawing primitive shapes"? Everybody does that; that's what rendering *is*.

Comment: Questions like this cannot be answered with yes or no. It depends on the context. You can try different approaches and compare the performance. Even then, the result depends on the hardware. Especially, if you compare a system with a _strong_ CPU, but a _weak_ GPU and a system with a _weak_ CPU, but a _strong_ GPU you get very different results.

Comment: But are these approaches similar to how games, and other graphical programs do it , are these approaches even viable?

Comment: @CheeseMan69: Both of your approaches allocate a buffer and send it to the GPU. What's the difference between them? What are the "basic shapes" you're drawing? Which metric do you want to compare these approaches -- performance, simplicity, flexibility...? What do you mean by "drawing ... in the vertex shader"? Vertex shaders do not draw anything. I'm sure game engines do different things in different places, depending on what's more appropriate.

Comment: @YakovGalka In the first approach the buffer is dynamic and I'll be sending data to the GPU every frame while in the second approach the buffer is static and doesn't change. By basic shapes I mean shapes like squares, triangles etc. In the second approach I'll provide the location of each shape in the buffer with vertex attributes then in the vertex shader I'll only multiply the appropriate shape's vertex data with the transform matrix and assign it to gl_Position.

Comment: @YakovGalka I want to know if these approaches are even reasonable, like generating and deleting shaders, vbo, vao, every frame is one way to do rendering but it's very inefficient and not viable. I want to know if these approaches are inefficient like that.

Comment: @CheeseMan69: How would your shapes move if the buffer isn't dynamic?

Comment: @YakovGalka I'll transform them with a matrix in the vertex shader

Comment: @CheeseMan69 how do you think the matrix gets onto the GPU? Won't the first approach also use a vertex shader with an MVP matrix (just like the legacy OpenGL pipeline)? It's best if you include a short snippet, drawing an animated triangle say, demonstrating each approach. Then people would have something specific to base an answer on.

Comment: @YakovGalka I'll be sending the matrix through a uniform, I'll be using a transformation matrix in both approaches. I do not have working code for both these approaches yet, do I have to give snippets of the implementation or of how the code for drawing things would look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two approaches are more alike than you pretend them to be. Both of them "preallocate a buffer on the GPU", both "fill it with data", and both have a vertex shader that will transform the data using an MVP matrix supplied from a uniform.

So far it seems that the only difference between your two approaches is that the 1st uploads your vertices every frame, while the 2nd uploads them only once.

If your models are indeed static -- then sure, by all means, go with the 2nd approach. If you have some sort of animation that cannot be accomplished in the vertex shader (e.g. you are drawing a GUI that reflows as the window size changes), then the 2nd approach is simply not applicable.

> @CheeseMan69: How would your shapes move if the buffer isn't dynamic?
>
> @YakovGalka I'll transform them with a matrix in the vertex shader

I guess you imagine having a single primitive in your buffer and then calling `glUniform` and `glDrawArrays` multiple times per frame? That would indeed be slow. You will be essentially submitting a different MVP matrix for each primitive. As a rule of thumb you want to draw many primitives with a single OpenGL call. To accomplish that you'll need to move your matrices to a UBO, SSBO, or an instanced vertex attribute. However an MVP matrix is going to take more bandwidth and computation than submitting the correct vertices of each primitive in the first place.

Comment: Will it be slow because of sending the uniforms every frame or will it be because of calling `glDrawArrays` every frame ? and how will sending the MVP matrix every frame take more bandwidth than sending all the vertex data to the GPU every frame, is what takes more bandwidth not dependent on the size of the data I'm sending ?

Comment: @CheeseMan69 The graphics stack is better at handling less commands with more data rather than lots of smaller commands. Re bandwidth: legacy GL MVP is 16-floats; a 3d triangle is only 9 floats; of course if you restrict yourself to 2d and, perhaps, only affine transformations, the numbers will be different. However, all this is negligible compared to the work the driver needs to do just to process your single `glUniform` and `glDrawArrays` commands. I personally never use `glUniform`, going straight with UBOs from the start.